# Footer taking 100% width but right side is missing

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make footer take 100% of the page, and as Chrome Devtools says, it really took full width, but one side is missing.
Photo: [image: footer problem]

Here's also some HTML and CSS

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: var(--jakarta);
}

html, body
{
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* for Internet Explorer, Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    overflow: visible;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}

.main {
    margin: 0px 165px 50px 165px;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
}

footer .nav-footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--blueish);
}

footer .nav-footer img {
    margin-left: 165px;
}

footer .nav-footer button {
    margin-right: 165px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <nav class="nav-footer">
      <img src="assets/images/logo-light.svg" alt="e-learning Logo">
      <button class="btn btn-get-started-head-section"><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Get Started</a></button>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

On bigger resolutions it's looking okay, but as soon as I start to go towards lower page width, footer starts missing more and more.
I have tried without setting width, with moving footer outside of main section element(that's actually right now).
Mi section class="main" element has left and right margin 165px so content needs to be 165px away from edges.
footer tag is outside of section.main and this shouldn't be happening.
Devtools says footer tag nor `.nav-footer` have any margins or paddings
Thank you!

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. It does not seem to reproduce the problem you have described or shown in your screenshot though. Can you edit your question and add to it so that your problem is reproduced?

Comment: It is not your footer what is creating that extra right side space it is your content/contents that are above the footer. Probably any of the contents above has a fixed width which is creating that space. You need to inspect from the browser or share more codes here.

Comment: Also you have an `<button>` with an `<a>`  tag inside of it. This is not valid HTML.  You can't nest an interactive element inside of another interactive element.

Comment: @ChrisBarr understood. thank you for pointing that mistakes to me!
Could this be Devtools bug itself? On my phone I happen to see footer okay, while on PC on same resolution can't see it at all.

Comment: No I doubt it's a devtools bug. Try this: in devtools start deleting elements outside of the footer until it looks like this problem is fixed. it might be something with strange positioning, or with margins, etc. Either that or edit your question to include as little code as you can that stuff reproduces the problem

Comment: @ChrisBarr that simple yet that effective, don't know how that didn't cross my mind earlier. Main head element is making problem because photo is overflowing from div to right edge of screen, that's dictated by design. Got it figured out now. 
Besides, it really only happens in devtools, 
I have tried variety of devices live and footer always shows as it should be.
Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are givin margin to main element and this is broken your code page. Try to out this margin in main element and run your code. Or show me all the code from this page.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: var(--jakarta);
}

html, body
{
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* for Internet Explorer, Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    overflow: visible;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}

.main {
    margin: 0px<= top margin  165px<= (this is margin Right) 50px <= bottom margin 165px; <= left margin
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
}

footer .nav-footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--blueish);
}

footer .nav-footer img {
    margin-left: 165px;
}

footer .nav-footer button {
    margin-right: 165px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <nav class="nav-footer">
      <img src="assets/images/logo-light.svg" alt="e-learning Logo">
      <button class="btn btn-get-started-head-section"><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Get Started</a></button>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: Here's whole CSS https://pastebin.com/s66Uau6n

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that your other contents are overflowing , You have given margin 165px right and left for main , try removing that , as I guess your footer looks fine , the problem is other elements are going out of zone because of that your footer is looking like this , try to inspect the main element as it is overflowing , try giving it a fixed width for mobile or tablets , like max-width:100vw or something , footer is not the issue in this I guess.

Comment: That was actually the problem, I had photo overflowing over body and everything, because that's dictated by design, and that was making it look weird.
Got it sorted now, thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't do the trick

Comment: Ok. Updated answer. Try this. Unfortunately, I have to guess because you only provided a piece of your code.